# How to use beautiful soup to parse a table and write it to a new file

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I've got some code, and  I'm currently trying to parse a table using beautifulsoup and get it written on a file but it keeps returning an error.

Here's the entire code:

```
import shlex
import subprocess
import os
import platform
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import csv
import pickle
import requests
from robobrowser import RoboBrowser

def rename_files():
    file_list = os.listdir(r"C:\\PROJECT\\pdfs")
    print(file_list)
    saved_path = os.getcwd()
    print('Current working directory is '+saved_path)
    os.chdir(r'C:\\PROJECT\\pdfs')
    for file_name in file_list:
        os.rename(file_name, file_name.translate(None, " "))
    os.chdir(saved_path)
rename_files()

def run(command):
    if platform.system() != 'Windows':
        args = shlex.split(command)
    else:
        args = command
    s = subprocess.Popen(args,
                         stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                         stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    output, errors = s.communicate()
    return s.returncode == 0, output, errors

# Change this to your PDF file base directory
base_directory = 'C:\\PROJECT\\pdfs'
if not os.path.isdir(base_directory):
    print "%s is not a directory" % base_directory
    exit(1)
# Change this to your pdf2htmlEX executable location
bin_path = 'C:\\Python27\\pdfminer-20140328\\tools\\pdf2txt.py'
if not os.path.isfile(bin_path):
    print "Could not find %s" % bin_path
    exit(1)
for dir_path, dir_name_list, file_name_list in os.walk(base_directory):
    for file_name in file_name_list:
        # If this is not a PDF file
        if not file_name.endswith('.pdf'):
            # Skip it
            continue
        file_path = os.path.join(dir_path, file_name)
        # Convert your PDF to HTML here
        args = (bin_path, file_name, file_path)
        success, output, errors = run("python %s -o %s.html %s " %args)
        if not success:
            print "Could not convert %s to HTML" % file_path
            print "%s" % errors
htmls_path = 'C:\\PROJECT'
with open ('score.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for dir_path, dir_name_list, file_name_list in os.walk(htmls_path):
        for file_name in file_name_list:
            if not file_name.endswith('.html'):
                continue
            with open(file_name) as markup:
                soup = BeautifulSoup(markup.read())
                text = soup.get_text()
                match = re.findall("PA/(\S*)", text)#To remove the names that appear, just remove the last (\S*), to add them is just add the (\S*), before it there was a \s*
                print(match)
                writer.writerow(match)
                for item in match:
                    data = item.split('/')
                    case_number = data[0]
                    case_year = data[1]

                    browser = RoboBrowser()
                    browser.open('http://www.pa.org.mt/page.aspx?n=63C70E73&CaseType=PA')
                    form = browser.get_forms()[0]  # Get the first form on the page
                    form['ctl00$PageContent$ContentControl$ctl00$txtCaseNo'].value = case_number
                    form['ctl00$PageContent$ContentControl$ctl00$txtCaseYear'].value = case_year

                    browser.submit_form(form, submit=form['ctl00$PageContent$ContentControl$ctl00$btnSubmit'])

                    # Use BeautifulSoup to parse this data
                    answer = browser.response.text
                    #print(answer)
                    soup = BeautifulSoup(answer)
                    #print soup.prettify()
                    status = soup.select('#Table1')
                    print (status)
                    with open('file_output.xls', 'w', 'utf-8') as f:
                      for tag in soup.select("#Table1"):
                        f.write(tag.prettify())
```

Here's the part where I try to parse and copy the table:

```
# Use BeautifulSoup to parse this data
                answer = browser.response.text
                #print(answer)
                soup = BeautifulSoup(answer)
                #print soup.prettify()
                status = soup.select('#Table1')
                print (status)
                with open('file_output.xls', 'w', 'utf-8') as f:
                  for tag in soup.select("#Table1"):
                    f.write(tag.prettify())
```

And here's the error I get:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROJECT\pdfs\converterpluspa.py", line 90, in <module>
    with open('file_output.xls', 'w', 'utf-8') as f:
TypeError: an integer is required
```

Comment: try this `tag = tag.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii')` before writing file

Comment: It promped the same error

Comment: can you show the value of `tag` variable ?

Comment: I thought tag was not a variable and a it was something like a function from beautifulsoup, sorry I'm new to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third argument for [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) is the `buffering` buffer size, not the `encoding`. The correct line in Python 3 would be:

```
with open('file_output.xls', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
```

while in Python 2 it would be:

```
import codecs
with codecs.open('file_output.xls', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
```

Comment: It worked but the file_output.xls was blank, nothing was written to it why is that?

Comment: What does the `print (status)` line before the open print? If it's `[]`, then nothing is matching the #Table1 selector.

Comment: Ok, I got it to work, I was missing a blank space on the beginning, but now it keeps deleting the information from other tables and writing new ones, and that's not what I want, I want it to write every table not just one and deleting the other ones, if you could help me out

Comment: Try opening 'file_outpu.xls' with the 'a' mode rather than 'w': this will append to the file rather than replacing it each time.

Comment: It is taking a lot of time to open the file, do you know why?

Comment: Ok, It doesn't even open the excel file, it crashes

Comment: What's the error? Check the file permissions, and maybe try writing to the file using a simple `with codecs.open('file_output.xls', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as f: f.write("Testing")`.